# Search files in sub- /folders from txt-file and save them in a txt-file as Paths

Tags: batch, search, textfiles

I want to search for different articlenumbers out of a list (txt-file) in a certain folder.
Then the paths of the files should be saved in a Txt-Output.

Also i would be nice if i could differ the filetype or the searchfolder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So let me see if got it right. Let's say the article numbers that you want to search are stored in Article.txt and there are a lot of txt files let's say in your desktop where the articles are stored inside these text files..

Something like this should store the paths to the files where there are occurrences of the articles:

```
@echo off
Set Source=%userprofile%\desktop\Teste\Files

if exist "Output.txt" del "Output.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /s /m /g:"Article.txt" "%Source%\*.txt"') do >>"Output.txt" echo Name: %%~nxa Path: %%~dpa

exit
```

[image]

Comment: Almost :) 
I have a Server with many folders and subfolders. The Windows search is not good enough to search many different words (chars). So i want to make a batch file that can search many different art.NR stored in a txt file and save the paths of the files in a txt.

Then its easy for me to just put my numbers (words/art.nr) in the txt file and start the batchfile.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, I added an /s to include subfolders and redirected to an output file. If you put that in batch script it should save everything in this output.txt.

Comment: Sorry thats not what im loking for.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more what you want.

Comment: You can compare it with the Windows Search function. The only difference is, that i need it as a BAT file that saves the results (paths) as a txt file. And it must be a txt file as input for the search :)

Comment: Can you give an example as of the output.txt should look like..

Comment: Do you want the batch file to ask for a search criteria is that it?

Comment: The txt file have all critirea, the batch just searches them and saves the a txt with the needed data (filename and path)

Comment: the format could be Name: xyz Path: XYZ, in one line.

Comment: @Plamsmageddon please see updated answer